# Excel First - Second Row Average Issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, moving-average

I have old Excel table that I need to manually fill and I made new Excel table where I used CTRL+T to fill in data automatically when typing formula in first row under the header/title cell.

My data is vertical in old:

```
Numbers     Average (for last 10 Numbers from Left Row)
5,780.00    
5,730.00    
6,600.00    
7,300.00    
6,120.00    
5,250.00    
5,210.00    
5,100.00    
5,770.00    
6,370.00    5923.00
6,000.00    5945.00
5,480.00    5920.00
5,120.00    5772.00
4,990.00    5541.00
```

This is how it should look, this is how I made it manually.
Formula is:

```
=IF(L11<>"",AVERAGE(L2:L11),"")
```

Where forumula is in M row (Average) and checking and calculating for L row (Numbers).
But for Table to auto-fill till last row, formula has to be made in first row, then Excel auto-fills.

```
Average:
5923.00
```

is from this numbers:

```
    Numbers
    5,780.00    
    5,730.00    
    6,600.00    
    7,300.00    
    6,120.00    
    5,250.00    
    5,210.00    
    5,100.00    
    5,770.00    
    6,370.00
```

How can Average formula for 10 vertical numbers from L row be inserted into any cell above 5923.00 in Average - M Row.

I do know how to fill row, I could copy formula, press CTRL + SHIFT + DOWN to find end of my table and paste formula, but when new data comes (imported CSV that updates), new data would not be filled, I need Excel to auto-fill it.

Comment: write vba to enter formula in 10th cell and copy it till end of table

Comment: That is not good solution. Then I would need VBA for everything, I mean that is good solution, but atm not acceptable :( Too big workbook too much work to do. Thanks for Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a test for which row the formula is in and only return a result if it's 11 or higher. Then you could enter it in the entire column table and it would fill automatically:

```
=IF(AND(ROW()>=11,L11<>""),AVERAGE(L2:L11),"")
```

`ROW()` returns the number of the row the fomula is in.

EDIT: Ok, here's a better one. Put this in M2 and copy down:

```
=IF(AND(ROW()>=11,L2<>""),AVERAGE(OFFSET($L$1,ROW()-10,0):OFFSET($L$1,ROW()-1,0)),"")
```

Comment: This is not quite correct. Cause when it paste formula to next row, wrong 10 cells are calculated in average, at M11 it needs to be L2:L11, and now its at M2, at M3 it is L3:L12, etc. so when we get to 11th row it is completely wrong range :(

Comment: I didn't change your basic formula. If the idea I offered sounds correct, then adjust your formula to suit. If not, good luck!

Comment: Idea sounds good, but I'm not sure how to adjust it. I need something similar to what you suggested Doug, my formula works when it is in M11 field, then average for above L2:L11 is correct, but when I copy paste your formula in row 2, and when it goes down, it will change M11 formula to wrong one :( Not sure if I know how to adjust it :(, please if you can, help me out. Thanks.

Comment: How not to change formula, cells, until condition is met. Like if() do it for this range, but don't increase range until criteria met.

Comment: Just paste it into M11 and then copy to the rest of the column. You'll see some #REF errors within the formulas in the first ten rows, but I don't think it matters.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I got it on my own, we got to same conclusion, OFFSET needed. Thanks a lot! I believe this could be useful stuff for ppl.

Answer (score 1):

Here is answer for all if needed, if you have by dates, old data up and new down, then average of first 10 items, can't be calculated in first 10 rows without issues where you have Average.
Here is solution for one way direction:

```
=IF(AND((ROW())>=11,L2<>""),AVERAGE(OFFSET(M2,-9,-1,10)),"")
```

What Offset does, is goes up +9 places from current cell M2, then it goes 1 cell left, and from there takes 10 down to mark the range.

IF if statement is wrong it doesn't go left and up, thus no error, after and including ROW 10 it's true statement.

And this is more complicated to use with Table in Excel, when you have sorting by date, when newest date is on top, bottom is data that you can use for average:

```
=IF($A$2>$A$3,AVERAGE(OFFSET(M2,0,-1,10)),IF(AND((ROW())>=11,L2<>""),AVERAGE(OFFSET(M2,-9,-1,10)),""))
```

I have first IF (A2>A3) that checks how is table sorted:
- if sorted newest - oldest (1st case) then it takes average from first row on the left, and down 10 places
- if sorted opposite, it goes as said: left one place, and up 9, then takes 10 range.

Works like a charm, bit long, but it works!

Comment: +1 good work. Please consider accepting one of our answers by clicking the empty checkmark next to it.